# Need to know how install a exe with a different program , oter than wine

Tags: executable

I use viewers for open sims and grids, Like second life and osgrid, I downloaded coolviewer and opened it with wine, it loaded ok but when I try to use it  goes to "not responding"   I  have to shut it down!! What causes this? I found were you get the terminal, but do not understand its im new to this ! Is there another program I can use to open window downloads?

Comment: .exe files are usually built for windows systems. You'll probably need to look into installing it using wine: https://www.winehq.org/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you probably can't. Wine occasionally works, as the other answers suggest, but more often than not the program will be unusable.

The best solution would be to simply find software made for Linux that will do the same thing as the "viewer.exe" that you so vaguely described. Without a description of this program though, nobody can recommended new software to you.

The second-best solution would be to install a Windows virtual machine with VirtualBox. You'll need a copy of Windows, and about an hour to install the virtual machine.

As a side note, why are you afraid of the terminal? The terminal is the single most advantageous thing about Linux over Windows (although there are many, many more advantages), and you're completely disregarding that. It's truly not that hard to learn.

So I hope this all helps you with your usage of Ubuntu!

Comment: I found my problem    it my inernet cable, it wasnt letting information threw, i  followed their  sugestion and i  did get cool viewer installas i use it to play on opensims, but now it goes into a not responding  when i open it and i have to do a force close! How can i corecct this?

Comment: im not afraid of it , i just didnt know how to find it , i do now, but dont understand the  formating ! and ty for your answer